# SQL Where clause based on Status

Tags: sql

```
Declare @Status nvarchar(25) = Null

Select * From Products
Where Type = 1
And
If Status is null, Don't add clause(means return all)
If Status = 'C', Add Status = 'Completed'
If Status = 'U', Add Status = 'Uncompleted'
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Don't call your variable the same as your column

```sql
Declare @MyStatus nvarchar(25) = Null

Select * From Products
Where Type = 1
AND (
  (MyStatus is null)
  OR (MyStatus = 'C' AND Status = 'Completed')
  OR (MyStatus = 'U' AND Status = 'Uncompleted')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to simply assign the desired value to your `@Status` variable then you can simply check for equality -

```
where Type = 1 and (@status = status or @Status is null);
```